# Derivative in 0

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I'm a highschool student and we don't learn maths in English. So please excuse me for my Math's English.
I'm doing an exercise and I can't answer its final question. Can you help me? Thank you!

Let $f$ a differentiable function on $\mathbb{R}$ which derivative is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

Let $g$ a function defined on $\mathbb{R}$ by:

$\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^*,\,\,g(x)=\dfrac{1}{2x}\int_{-x}^xf(t)\,dt$ and $g(0)=f(0)$.

1- Prove that $g$ is continuous at $0$.

2- For all $x\ne 0$ calculate $g'(x)$ according to $f(x)$ and $g(x)$.

I answerd both questions. For the seconde one I found:
$$\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^*,\,\,g'(x)=\dfrac{f(x)+f(-x)-2g(x)}{2x}$$

Here's the last question.

3- Prove that $g$ is differentiable at $0$ and that $g'(0)=0$.

Thank you.

edit: That's what I tried:

$\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{g(x)-g(0)}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{1}{2}\left(\dfrac{\frac{F(x)}{x}-f(0)}{x}+\dfrac{\frac{F(-x)}{-x}-f(0)}{x}\right) $

where $F(x)=\int_0^xf(t)dt$

Comment: Do you have any thoughts about the last question?

Comment: you made a mistake on your derivative. The derivative of $\frac{1}{x}$ is $\frac{-1}{x^2}$, you're missing an $x$

Comment: **Hint:** Let $\varphi \colon I\to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function and given $a\in I$, assume that $\varphi_{|I\setminus\{a\}}$ is differentiable. If $\lim \limits_{x\to a}(\varphi(x))\in \mathbb R$, then $\varphi'(a)$ exists and it equals this limit.

Comment: symplectomorphic: Yes to calculate $\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{g(x)-g(0)}{x}$ but I don't find it.

Comment: Matt B: I checked up and found that I didn't make a mistake. I'm sure it's correct.
Git Gud: that's what's I'm trying to do.

Comment: @Scientifica Nevermind, what I said doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that

$$g'(0)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\int_{-x}^x f(t)dt-2f(0)x}{2x^2}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)+f(-x)-2f(0)}{4x}$$ $$=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f'(x)-f'(-x)}{4}=\frac{f'(0)-f'(0)}{4}=0,$$

where we have applied L'Hospital rule in the second and third equalities.

**A clarification**

Note that because of the fundamental theorem of calculus $F(x)=\int_0^xf(t)dt$ is differentiable at any point where $f$ is continuous and $F'(x)=f(x).$ So $\int_{-x}^xf(t)dt=F(x)-F(-x)$ is differentiable at any point and the same happens to $\int_{-x}^xf(t)dt-2f(0)x.$ For this reason we can apply L'Hospital rule in the second equality.

Comment: Thank you! But first we need to prove that $g$ is differentiable at $0$ to apply l'Hospital rule. And please about $g'(0)=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\int_{-x}^x f(t)dt}{4x^2}$

Well $g'(0)=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\dfrac{g(x)-g(0)}{x}=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\int\limits_{-x}^xf(t)\, dt-2f(0)x}{2x^2}$

By L'Hospital rule we find $\dfrac{f'(0)-f'(0)}{4}$. It's $0$, no problem but still we don't know why $g$ is differentiable at $0$.

Comment: I have just fixed the answer.

Comment: Yes you're right! Thank you very much! (I was locking on $g$).